# Is this site also aimed at UX enthusiasts who are not professionals?

Tags: discussion

The [tour](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tour) for the site says the following:

> UX Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for User Experience Designers, Information Architects, and Human Computer Interaction researchers.

All of these are professional jobs. Does this mean that the site is not aimed at those who are merely interested in the subject of UX as a hobby?

This was inspired by [Who is the core audience of UX Stack Exchange?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1985/27666), in which the highest voted answer said that "We're here for professionals, or enthusiasts of UX", in contrast to the tour text.

If it is targeted at both professionals and enthusiasts of UX, perhaps the site description could be changed.

Answer (score 2):

One of the *problems* of Area 51 (where this site was proposed) is that it asks you to "describe your audience" as a way to define a site — and that frequently results is a type of "members only" description which typically adds very little to having the site title on its own.

Certainly everyone is invited — we're not checking credentials at the door — so while we don't typically *describe* a site as being "aimed" at enthusiasts explicitly, certainly every well-asked question should expect to get a great answer based on the on the merits of the post!

I guess there is no harm in discussing a tweak to the description page, but I wouldn't obsess over it *too* much. The single most important design element of a site is the questions on the front page, and what that front page is telling me is that I shouldn't fret too much over my (lack of) professional credentials wondering if I'd be welcomed to ask a question on this site.

This site is doing *very* well.

Comment: The site is certainly doing well, but I still think it would be a good change to make. Since the tour page is what most new users will see, we want for it to reflect the reality of our site.

Comment: Fair enough....

Comment: I don't believe this site came from Area 51, did it? This site actually existed prior to the whole Stack Exchange model. It was migrated in at that time.

Comment: @DA01 Userexperience.com(?) was an SE 1.0 site. I do not recall if any actual data was migrated, but the proposal itself did start in Area 51 — http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728?phase=definition

Comment: It was originally http://uxexchange.com/ and it existed back in June 2010 (the first mention I made of it). Not sure when it actually started up. All the data was migrated, though. I do recall that.

Comment: @DA01 Yes, that all rings true.